# Dynamic Parameter in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I use the [Jenkins Dynamic Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/dynamicparameter-plugin) in a `Jenkinsfile`?

What I am looking for is a Jenkinsfile snippet that:

- Enables the `Build with Parameters` option in the Jenkins job
- When selected, a script that populates a list that can be used `Dynamic Choice Parameters` is populated and the user will see a drop down list.

When trying:

1. `Pipeline syntax` in the Jenkins editor
2. Selecting `properties: Set job properties` as `Sample step`
3. Selecting `This project is parameterized`
4. Using `Dynamic Choice Parameter`
5. Enter values for `Name`, `Choice Script`, `Remote Script` etc
6. `Generate Pipeline Script`

I get the following template:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        <object of type com.seitenbau.jenkins.plugins.dynamicparameter.ChoiceParameterDefinition>
    ]), 
    pipelineTriggers([])
])
```

i.e. the generated pipeline script does not contain the data that I have entered in step `5.` above. How can I modify `parameters` so that parameter name, choices, etc will be visible to the user?

---

Jenkins version: 2.19.3
Dynamic Parameter Plugin version: 0.2.0

Answer (score 11):

there is no need anymore for the Jenkins Dynamic Plugin anymore. Just use the normal choice or string parameter and have the value(s) updated by groovy code.

```java
#!/bin/groovy

def envs = loadEnvs();

properties([
   parameters([
      choice(choices: envs, description: 'Please select an environment', name: 'Env')
   ])
])

node { 
   try {
      stage('Preparation'){
...
```

If you use the choice parameter be aware the you must provide a string where the values are separated by a new line.

For example:

```
"a\nb\nc"
```

If you really need to plugin, then vote on this issue [JENKINS-42149](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42149).

Comment: In what version of Jenkins? I'm running 2.3 and get the error "No such DSL method 'parameters' found among steps"

Comment: It works, but it creates new parameter and persists values in build parameters, if actual values (for example list of maven versions) changed -parameters values not updated, seems loadEnvs() not executed every time or smth like this

Comment: This is a scripted pipeline.  Does it work in declarative pipeline? If so, how?  What's the syntax?

Comment: The problem with this is changes to build properties only affect _future_ builds -- changing the parameters on the current build doesn't help because the `properties()` function runs after the user has already provided the build parameters for that build