# Can a Jenkins Pipeline write/configure a separate Jenkins job?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've got a Jenkins pipeline that builds docker images and tags them with the git hash. I also have another parameterized Jenkins pipeline that takes in a couple of string/choice parameters for deployment of the docker images. I'd love for the build pipeline to append some strings to the choice parameters in the deployment pipeline, so that when a user runs the deployment pipeline, he/she is just presented with a list of recently successfully built docker images to choose from.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be for your first job to set an environment variable with the list of recent built image tabs (one per line).
See [declarative pipeline `environment` directive](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment).

Then, following "[Dynamic Parameter in Jenkinsfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230455/6309)", you can use an external function like:

```java
#!/bin/groovy

def envs = loadEnvs();

properties([
   parameters([
      choice(choices: envs, description: 'Please select an image tag', name: 'Env')
   ])
])
```

That should be enough to build a choice parameter list.

"[Pipeline: How to manage user inputs](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204986450-Pipeline-How-to-manage-user-inputs) " (May 10th, 2017, two weeks ago) shows an alternative command, but not valid in the [Declarative Pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/):

> You have to use the `input` step to achieve it.
>   It will give you something like this :

```java
stage 'promotion'
def userInput = input(
 id: 'userInput', message: 'Let\'s promote?', parameters: [
 [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'uat', description: 'Environment', name: 'env'],
 [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'uat1', description: 'Target', name: 'target']
])
echo ("Env: "+userInput['env'])
echo ("Target: "+userInput['target'])
```

Comment: Are you sure that the last part is for the declarative pipelines? This feels a lot like scripted pipeline to me. AFAIK you can't set variables in declarative, and the `stage` syntax looks like the already deprecated one from scripted pipelines. IMHO the only way to use `input` in a declarative pipeline is to externalize the `input` into a function which is then called as a normal (blocking) build step.

Comment: The difference between `parameters` and `input` is that the first asks for feedback before the build starts, while the latter one can be used at any time _during_ the build.

Comment: @StephenKing You are correct. I have amended the answer to make that clearer: there does not seem to be a direct DSL native solution.